# How to create textarea and edittext with border and fixed label?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new to Android. I am wondering how can we get a bordered Edittext and Textarea like we have in HTML something like this:

[image]

I am finding it hard to get such output in Lollipop devices as it shows as a line and a floating label.

Comment: Make custom shape in _drawable_ folder

Answer (score 0):

In situation like this according to Google docs you would prefer **TextInputLayout**

For example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/password_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                    android:textColor="#777777"
                    android:textColorHint="#777777"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_20"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/input_password"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```